# Loading associated resources in Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm working on my second Ember project, and first using Rails on the backend. I'm struggling with loading associated data through my API in a nested route. The association is simple: a folder has many media_files in my backend (I'm aware snake case is against convention but trying to work around it).

When I do the following, I get the correctly nested route (folders/show/media_files) and no complaints when loading the template, but the data is empty in the console and doesn't render in the template.

Thank you for your time.

Here is my routing:

```
Router.map(function() {
 this.route('folders', function(){

   this.route('show', {
      path: ':folder_id'
   }, function() {
      this.route('media_files', {resetNamespace: true}, function (){
   });
  });

 });
});
```

Here are my associations:

Folder:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  media_files: DS.hasMany('media_file')
});
```

Media Files:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  duration: DS.attr('number'),
  createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
  folder: DS.belongsTo('folder')
});
```

Here is the call to the media files index:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.modelFor("folders/show").get("media_files");
  }
});
```

My URL is folders/folder_id/media_files, same as in my API. The JSON there looks like this:

```
{
   media_files: [
{
    id: 513009,
    url: null,
    project_id: 999,
    batch_id: 1268,
    duration: 30556,
    rush: false.....
```

Comment: Can you share code for `folders/show` route?

Comment: It's empty, because Ember is finding the data by default. My folders show page is working. The Media Files index for that folder is nested underneath in an outlet. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: What adapter are you using and do you mark `media_files` as embedded?

Comment: Active Model Adapter, and no, is that required? Also, would you nest media files in your folder api call, or use a dedicated Rails controller as I am:

Comment: `def index
        media_files =     Project.find(999).batches.find(params[:folder_id]).media_files
        render json: media_files
      end`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have experience with Active Model Adapter so I can't help.

Comment: Ok thank you anyway!

Comment: Can you share your template you are trying to render? I would also suggest you share a jsbin or spend some time rephrasing your question, because your explanations are very confusing. There are a lot of missing pieces to actually troubleshoot it. Thanks!